# PC won't boot, takes me straight to BIOS and won't show boot options

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd, bios

PC SPECIALIST - Vortex GT Gaming PC - Intel® Core™ i5, GTX 1650, 1 TB HDD & 256 GB SSD

I bought a PC just under two months ago but it froze yesterday and I had to power it down by holding the power button.

Now it goes straight to the UEFI BIOS Utility interface. It used to show two options in the boot priority section (I'm guessing the HDD and SSD) but now it won't show anything. The HDD seems to be showing in the Storage information but no sign of the SSD. And if I press Boot Menu (F8) it says "The system cannot find any bootable devices":

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

I've played around with the boot settings and managed to get it to show the HDD in the boot priority list but when I try to boot it says "reboot and select proper boot device:

[image: screenshot]

Not sure what's going on and I'm not very technical at all.
Here are some shots of the boot options in the advanced settings (which I believe are now set to default) in case it helps:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

> **I bought a PC just under two months ago** but it froze yesterday ...  It used to show two options in the boot priority section ....  And if
> I press Boot Menu (F8) it says "The system cannot find any bootable
> devices":

Make arrangements with the vendor to return it under warrranty or repair it under warranty.

It is possible that forcing the machine off corrupted both drives but not likely.